# Why is a for loop on data.table row index slower than on data.frame?

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, data.table

I am definitely confused on why accessing a data.table by row index is slower than data.frame. Any suggestions how i can access each row of data.table sequentially in loop that is faster?

```
m = matrix(1L, nrow=100000, ncol=100)

DF = as.data.frame(m)
DT = as.data.table(m)

identical(DF[100, ], DT[100, ])
[1] FALSE

> all(DF[100, ], DT[100, ])
[1] TRUE

> system.time(for (i in 1:1000) DT[i,])
   user  system elapsed 
  5.440   0.000   5.451 

R> system.time(for (i in 1:1000) DF[i,])
   user  system elapsed 
  2.757   0.000   2.784
```

Comment: The simplest explanation is `[.data.table` does a *lot more* things than `[.data.frame`.

Comment: How may iterate the rows of the data.frame by row index faster then ?

Comment: I've created a [FR #5260](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5260&group_id=240&atid=978) here. Thanks for reporting. It should be possible to gain more speed.

Comment: @user3147662, why don't you provide more information about the problem you are trying to solve by iterating through rows of a `data.table`?  You can do amazing powerful things without explicit iteration.  Also, you should probably do that as a separate question.

Comment: Speeding up `[.data.table` is on the agenda. But using a loop to recurse through each row of a data.table is a very rare (if not absolutely unnecessary) scenario. As @BrodieG asks, what exactly is your task?

Comment: I need to do pairwise row comparison between 2 data frame/tables. That means get each row in the first object to compare all rows in the other object, i.e. N x M comparisons. And each object can have 1e06 rows. Love to get help on how do this better.

Comment: What do you mean by "comparison"? You'll need a cross join, but it would be good if you could reshape your data.tables to long format.

Comment: A nice starting point would be to edit your post with what your actual task is, clearly, and with producible examples, and showing your output.

Comment: I am looping over a DT and also noticed the overhead. For each row, I run a substantial series of function calls (with branching logic) and then write one or more rows to a file. To avoid this `[.data.table` overhead am I supposed to just wrap it all it up in a `function(row) {...}` and do an `apply` function?

Comment: @user3147662 please consider accepting provided answer, or provide feedback what doesn't work for you. I just double check we are good on those timings in https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/542

Answer (score 7):

A `data.table` query has more arguments (and it does more) so the small overhead of `DT[...]` is larger than `DF[...]`. This overhead adds up if you loop it. The intended use of `data.table` is to have it execute a large complex operation few times, rather than small trivial calculations multiple times. So let's reformulate your test:

```
> system.time(DT[seq(len=nrow(m)),])
 user  system elapsed 
0.08    0.02    0.09 
> system.time(DF[seq(len=nrow(m)),])
 user  system elapsed 
0.08    0.05    0.13
```

Here, they are about the same.  Since we only have one DT call, the overhead isn't that apparent because the overhead is only executed once.  In your case you executed it 100K times (unnecessarily, I might add).  If you are using `data.table` and you are making calls to it thousands of times, you are probably using it wrong.  There almost certainly is a way to reformulate so you can have just one or a few `data.table` calls that do the same thing.

Also, note that even my reformulated test here is pretty trivial, which is why `data.table` performs comparably to `data.frame`.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with your first line? What's the overhead  with each data.table statement?

Comment: `[.data.table` is 1000 lines of code when deparsed, whereas `[.data.frame` is 145.  # of lines of code is definitely not a great comparison of overhead, but clearly `data.table` needs to do waaay more than `[.data.frame` to appropriate react to different inputs.  This isn't bad at all, it just means that if you're going to do a completely trivial calculation with `data.table`, and keep calling `[.data.table` each time, you'll notice the overhead associated with handling all the special conditions that `[data.table` manages.  Since this is not the correct usage of data table, it isn't a problem

Comment: Right all along. But we could get more speed-up. I'll write back once I manage test some ideas.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit out the first line to what you say in your comment. It's not clear you're talking about `[.data.table`.

Comment: @Arun, do you mean the line that starts "`[.data.table` is 1000 lines of code..."?  I'm confused.

Comment: +1 I'm clear. The same concept should be familiar to SQL folk too: you don't send 100k dynamic SQL statements (or sproc calls) to the SQL Server one by one do you (that's slow due to the overhead of each call); you do it in bulk in one query.

Comment: @BrodieG, the way I understand `each data.table statement` is that, it also includes `set(...)`, `setcolorder(..)` etc.. These are all `data.table` statements as well. They don't have any (unusual) overhead.

Comment: @MattDowle, the point of the question is *not* why `[.data.table` is slow. It's on *why it's slower than `[.data.frame`?*. At least for this case (and other basic/easy cases), we can catch it earlier (I think). Also the `for-loop` constructing output  (in `!missing(j)`) could be done in C maybe? Not sure. So I think it could be faster, although I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @Arun Agreed on the first sentence, I edited. We could reduce the overhead yes. Maybe we could detect being looped more than 1000 times and issue a warning `"Please don't loop calls to DT[...]. See ?xyz help page."`.